# Aviso do sistema "sua pergunta parece ser bem subjetiva e há boa chance de ser fechada"

Tags: debate, suporte, pergunta-específica

Fiz esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157135/o-que-%C3%A9-build-e-qual-%C3%A9-a-sua-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-a-ide) lá no SOpt a respeito do termo **build**, entretanto, um aviso que recebi me chamou muito a atenção e confesso que me deixou até um pouco surpreso. Foi a primeira vez que recebi este aviso e ele dizia o seguinte:

> Sua pergunta parece ser bem subjetiva e há boa chance de ser fechada

Veja a imagem do aviso:
[image: aviso]

Até achei interessante este aviso e pode vir a ser útil para os usuários no momento da elaboração da pergunta, porem, ele me deixou com algumas dúvidas que irei listar logo abaixo.

## Dúvidas

Levando em consideração este recurso eu gostaria que a comunidade me esclarecesse os seguintes pontos:

- Isto é um novo recurso ou já existe faz tempo?
- Quais critérios o sistema usa para determinar se a pergunta é
  subjetiva ao ponto de ser fechada?
- Interpretando esta mensagem de uma maneira mais simples (ou ao pé da
  letra :P) posso entender que perguntas "subjetivas" não se encaixa no
  modelo de perguntas definido na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), no entanto, na
  seção [Perguntando, e em Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de
  fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) da central de ajuda, tem alguns pontos que dizem que
  perguntas "subjetivas" podem ser feitas, sendo assim, eu gostaria de
  saber quais pontos específicos na minha pergunta contribui para que
  ela seja subjetiva de uma forma que ela deva ser fechada?

Comment: Como nunca peguei eu não sei, em inglês o índice de acerto era bom. Esse já errou. Existia desde o começo, são as palavras que disparam isso. Tem recursos, textos s práticas adotadas que não batem. Se seguirmos o que o sistema e a central de ajuda indica, fecha metade das perguntas e uns 80% deve ser negativado :D

Comment: eu já recebi umas 3 vezes

Comment: Muito interessante e util este o aviso, principalmente para novos usuarios,  que podem se policiar melhor antes de postar a pergunta.

Comment: Não sabia desse recurso, achei interessante.

Comment: Eu também já recebi esse aviso antes, ele é um recurso antigo. Assim como a sua pergunta a minha também não foi fechada e foi bem pontuada (só não me lembro exatamente qual era). Como funciona? Não faço ideia. Chutaria que ele procura por termos-chave, como "O que é", "Qual o melhor", ou coisas do tipo, mas o funcionamento exato é um mistério. Apesar da ideia ser interessante tenho dúvidas com relação a sua eficácia.